# Can we Click a button on servlet using post parameters?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, post

Ok. The question might be incredibly stupid but I am facing this issue as an actual problem.

My client has a servlet based page with a couple of dropdowns and a submit button.

On selecting dropdown values and clicking the button, an ajax call gets some report data which is displayed on the same page.

My job is to get this report data.

From my end I can only pass post parameters to the servlet in following format:

```
postDataOne["comboId"] = "null";
map<string, string> postDataTwo;
postDataTwo["reportName"] = "6";
postDataTwo["reportType"] ="dam";
postDataTwo["dam_rapor"] = "6";
postDataTwo["settlement_rapor"] = "0";
```

Doing this just sets the value os all dropdowns on the servlet.

Is it possible to click the button using post params?

Comment: Please be more specific : `click the button using post params` just doesn't mean anything

Comment: can I click button by sending javascript code as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own description, clicking the button just executes some JavaScript function which sends an AJAX request with post parameters. If you send the same AJAX request, you'll get the same response.

The server doesn't care how the request was sent. Whether it was sent by clicking on a button, or a link or any other action is completely irrelevant. The only thing that matters is the URL, method, parameters, headers and cookies of the request it receives.

Comment: In this case, I am dealing with a servlet. How can I find the server link from the page code?

Comment: Read its source code. Right-click, View page source. Or use Firebug, go to the network tab, click on the button, and see what request is sent. Or read the documentation and source code of the servlet, to know what it expects.